# Problem find joined table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have model represent association rule (Body => Head)

```
def Item
has_many :heads
has_many :bodies
...
end

def Rule
has_many :heads
has_many :bodies
...
end

def Body
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :rule
...
end

def Head
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :rule
...
end
```

I want to find rule that have body's item matched items specified and want to access its head via Rule but I can't do like

```
def Rule
has_many :heads
has_many :bodies
has_many :item, :through => :heads
has_many :item, :through => :bodies
...
end
```

What should I change and do to accomplish this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I come up with this solution

```
class Rule
  has_many :heads
  has_many :bodies
  ...
end
class Body
  belongs_to :rule
  has_many :items, :as => :rulable
end
class Head
  belongs_to :rule
  has_many :items, :as => :rulable
end
class Item
  belongs_to :rulable, :polymorphic => true`
end
```

Don't sure if this is a good solution, but this is what I use for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Rule
  has_many :heads
  has_many :bodies
  has_many :head_items, :through => :heads
  has_many :body_items, :through => :bodies
  ...
end
```

You need to different has_many associations for each.

Comment: I should have head_items and body_items models as inheritance of items ?